# extracting future ex-dividend dates with python

Tags: python, finance, stock, quantitative-finance, yfinance

I have been looking to find a reliable source to gather upcoming ex-dividend dates and information regarding the dividend amount.
it seems that yfinance had an api `yf.Ticker('MSFT').info['exDividendDate']` but this is not working anymore.
I'd like to be able to have a list ['MSFT', 'AAPL',...] and receive all their up coming ex-dividend dates and the amount of dividend they will be paying.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following Python library to be useful. here is the code that I used to resolve this problem:

```
pip install finance-calendars

from finance_calendars import finance_calendars as fc

today_ex_dividend_dates =fc.get_dividends_today()
ex_dividend_on_specific_day = fc.get_dividends_by_date(datetime(2023, 4, 14, 0, 0))
```